# why not using Request.Cookies.Clear() in ASP.NET web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, webforms

I searched here on the stackoverflow about removing all cookies from site, but couldn't find a single answer suggesting the use of  `Request.Cookies.Clear()` method.

What's the difference between:

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

and:

```
Request.Cookies.Clear();
```

Thanks in advance!
and sorry for my bad language, English is not my native!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Calling [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.remove%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.clear%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will remove it from the server side collection held by [Request.Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies.aspx) (which is a copy of the cookies your client sent to you). However that does not cause the server to instruct the *client browser* to remove the cookie. To do that you need to set the timeout as you have indicated above (see [MSDN - How To: Delete a Cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178195%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the official guidance).